# ubuntu-desktop package broken for Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: unity

I'm trying to install ubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu Server 14.04. But error is thrown as packages are broken. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticed the same during yesterday, thought it was bound to this (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1654008) and was seeing the same package break during a netinstallation of 14.04.

It seems the issue was present at least on some official mirrors in EU and Asia, a colleague of mine just informed that it was solved now.

Doing a test installation now today went through fine. So try again :)

Comment: Yeah, it started working for me as well. Thanks